# How to forbid casting literals to class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

With TypeScript it's allowed to case an object literals to a class as follows:

```
let businessObj = new ScenarioController(<FormatService>{ 
    format: x => x
});
```

It is possible to **forbid** such casts in compiler or linter, or something?

In many cases it's **misused** by devs, and causes many problems with maintenance.

Comment: How is it misused and what problems does it cause?

Comment: @Sefe - it fakes that you have an instance of a class, with methods and all possible properties. But in runtime you discover that some methods or properties aren't there. In fact, `prototype` is not set. The problem I found what that the FormatService was extended with new methods, but following construction ignored them (until runtime)

Comment: Are you mixing JavaScript and TypeScript? If you stay in TS, this should not happen, since you can use classes instead of extending the prototype.

Comment: @Sefe - nope, pure TypeScript. But all instances of standard TypeScript classes have prototype set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a out-of-box linter that forbids type assertion.

If a code guideline (for human) is not viable, it should be possible to write a simple detector with `typescript`'s compiler API (which provides AST traversing methods, see [Using the Compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#traversing-the-ast-with-a-little-linter)).